# Error while installing matplotlib Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip

The operating system is Windows 10 64 bit. I tried to do the following:

```
pip install matplotlib.
```

Didn't work. Then I tried as it is written in https://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html#build-requirements:

```
python -mpip install -U pip
python -mpip install -U matplotlib
```

Then somewhere I read that setuptools upgrade can resolve the problem. I tried it with:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
easy_install -U setuptools
```

The response is always the same:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pqlhz7ux\matplotlib\
```

Can you help me? Python version is 3.7.0

```
BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
matplotlib: yes[2.2.2]
                python: yes
[3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 2
7 2018, 04:06:47) [MSC v.1914 32 bit (Intel)]]
 platform: yes [win32]

REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                 numpy: yes
[not found. pip may install it below.]
      install_requires: yes
[handled by setuptools]
                libagg: yes
[pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not be found. Using local copy.]
              freetype: no
[The C/C++ header for freetype
                        (freetype2\ft2build.h) could not be
found.  You may need to install the development pack age.]
                   png: no
[The C/C++ header for png (png.h) could not be
                        found.  You may need to install the development 
package.]
                 qhull: yes
[pkg-config information for 'libqhull' could not be found. Using local copy.]
```

Comment: Can we have some of the traceback?

Comment: Try opening your command prompt in administrator mode.

Comment: @TorinMay Still the same problem.

Comment: @MoxieBall From what I understand I should install the mentioned packages. However, while installing numpy the same error occured and it also complains about Microsoft Visual C++ 14 not being installed, but it is. libagg,libqhull - No matching distribution

Comment: Make sure those C++ headers are installed and in your PATH. Other than that, I am not sure

Comment: @MoxieBall Ok, thank you for your time!

Answer (score -5):

[image: Here is the screenshot attached to install the library from the source]

I have attached the Screenshot showing how to install the library using the source file

Comment: post as text, not a screenshot.